# Potential MITM attack on email server

Tags: man-in-the-middle

I'm facing an issue with an e-mail server. I think someone is performing a MITM attack because outlook is asking to users to install a new invalid SSL certificate.

I put DNSSEC to our records but still happens. The only option that I can see right now is create a VPN tunnel from our office to the web hosting.

A traceroute is showing 21 hops to reach the server so I'm guessing some else could be intercepting our communications.

It would be great to hear some else opinion on what might be happening.

Comment: You're sure the existing SSL certificate on the exchange server hasn't expired?

Comment: There is really no clear answer here, especially since we don't even know why the certificate is considered not valid. Can you connect to the server using `openssl` and get its certificate that way, and then see what's wrong? It could be as simple as the certificate being expired or replaced by a new one that doesn't include the domain you're using to connect to it.

Comment: Can you please post the certificate being asked to install?

Comment: yes we renew the ssl and is not about to expire, we're using letsencrypt and comodo. sometimes is coming correct certificate sometimes is coming  wrong certificate..

Comment: Have you looked into any known issues between Microsoft exchange servers and LetsEncrypt certificates? I did a quick search for anything that is known and came back with a couple possibilities for you.

http://serverfault.com/questions/767164/how-to-fix-issues-with-letsencrypt-certificate-chains-on-windows-server

Also, I would rule out MITM as soon as possible by checking the unknown hop ips for any malicious history using VirusTotal.com OR, if it's worse, you will have unidentified server hops within your network.

Comment: thank you all for help me out, issue seems to be resolved. it was not our server side, it was hosting side. I think they purge DNS cache.